# unregistering a class

Tags: python, scripting

I have made a new object for the Add > Mesh menu and I would like to unregister it but when I try to with:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   unregister()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\add_tetrahedron.py", line 63, in <module>
    register()
  File "\add_tetrahedron.py", line 59, in unregister
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_add_object)
RuntimeError: unregister_class(...):, missing bl_rna attribute from 'OrderedMeta' instance (may not be registered)
```

I've tried looking for this error but, I can't find what I'm doing wrong. I can't find anything about bl_rna anywhere.

I'm using Blender 2.79b

The register functions look like this:

```
# Registration

def add_object_button(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(
        OBJECT_OT_add_object.bl_idname,
        text="Tetrahedron",
        icon='PLUGIN')

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_add_object)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.append(add_object_button)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_add_object)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.remove(add_object_button)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: the `register()` function works just fine.

Answer (score 8):

**Consult python docs for a better explanation**

> Since there is no `main()` function in Python, when the command to run a
> python program is given to the interpreter, the code that is at level
> 0 indentation is to be executed. However, before doing that, it will
> define a few special variables. `__name__` is one such special variable.
> If the source file is executed as the main program, the interpreter
> sets the `__name__` variable to have a value “`__main__`”.

> If this file is
> being imported from another module, `__name__` will be set to the
> module’s name.
> `__name__` is a built-in variable which evaluates to the name of the current module. Thus it can be used to check whether the current
> script is being run on its own or being imported somewhere else by
> combining it with if statement, as shown below.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

which when run from text editor in above case registers the class `OBJECT_OT_add_object`  When run again it has "no idea" that it is the same class as registered before. ( Hence the error if you try to unregister)

If however the class is registered when enabled as an addon it will be in that addon modules namespace `my_addon.OBJECT_OT_add_object` (ie `__name__ == "my_addon"`) and will be the same class when unregistered from the addon.

This is included to test scripts in the text editor.  Removing it will have no consequence if installed as an addon.

Have a feeling an issue here is:

When testing such scripts it has the tendency to append and append and append the item to the menu.

A solution to this is `bpy.ops.script.reload()` which in 2.7x has the shortcut <kbd>F8</kbd> or can be run in the python console.  *Recommend writing a little script to prepend it to the text editor and console headers for convenience*

**EDIT** In 2.8 reload scripts is also  available via  the *`Blender > System > Reload Scripts`* menu.

**Import the text script as a module**

Further to this. To test a script in the python console.  For example the simple panel template.

This will give the script a "namespace"

```
>>> foo = D.texts['ui_panel_simple.py'].as_module()
```

Can call the register method

```
>>> foo.register()
```

and then later unregister with

```
>>> foo.unregister()
```

somewhat more closely emulating it being an addon.

Comment: Damn, When testing addons from the text editor menus get appended over and over again, `bpy.ops.script.reload()` will be a life saver. Thanks!

Comment: Well well well  it's the new heavy hitter in the python questions. Had to laugh at the +4 to overscore for an underscore.. In 2.8 reload scripts is also  available via  the _`Blender > System > Reload Scripts`_ menu.

Comment: Eheh low hanging fruit, I know. Finally started dipping my toes in Blender Python,and quite enjoying it, but still very green at it. I knew of the menu entry, but calling it from script directly saves some clicks

Comment: Go in up to your knees with [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/182445/15543)  (Needs that how to add images link btw) Going by the picture not sure how would do this via the UI, .. delete a hole and grid fill?  Reckon you will enjoy scripting coming from your extensive knowledge on how to use the UI to get things done.

Answer (score 4):

You can get your registered class via types objects. For example if you have registered your own node tree:

```
class MyCustomTree(bpy.types.NodeTree):
    bl_idname = 'CustomTreeType'
    bl_label = "Custom Node Tree"
    bl_icon = 'NODETREE'

bpy.utils.register_class(MyCustomTree)
```

for getting this class you should write next code:

```
TreeClass = bpy.types.NodeTree.bl_rna_get_subclass_py('CustomTreeType')
```

Then you can use it for class unregistration

```
bpy.utils.unregister_class(TreeClass)
```