# Is there a way to save the textures used inside a .blend file to a PC?

Tags: image

I want to save the textures or images used in a certain .blend file to my PC so that I can use them for my other projects.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 3):

To import all the materials used in an old blend file, use the *Append* function. If the images that are used in the appended materials are not packed into the blend file but are saved in a folder, make sure that you don't remove this folder, otherwise your new file won't be able to find them automatically. If the images were packed in the old file they will automatically be in the new one.

[image]

You can export all the images packed into a folder with *File > External Data > Unpack All Into Files*, if you want to keep the images packed into the file, don't save the file when closing.

Comment: Sorry if replying to my comment I removed re `_File > External Data > Unpack All into Files_` and follow the prompts.. but it does that doesn't it?

Comment: I've made a mistake, what you say will unpack, so it won't keep the images within the file, what I meant is: is it possible to export all the packed images of a file, all at once, instead of doing some one by one "save image" in the UV Editor? It would be a kind of "save all images"

Comment: Won't matter if don't save the blend after.  Can be done quite simply via script by setting filepath and saving or with save as op... akin to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182986/upgrading-an-old-python-script-change-all-image-paths-at-once only that one is changing paths not saving files.

Comment: IIRC @DrSybren wrote an addon "Splode" or similar play on explode  that takes a blend and expands everything into a folder structure of  libs like a reverse append if you like.  All said as answered append is prob the go here.

Comment: oh ok yes if I don't save it will keep them packed, thanks  ;)

Comment: If you have a tick could you look at https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182445/split-long-thin-faces-into-less-elongated-ones Haven't DL'd the file ... just looking at the screenies feel my modelling skills are too primitive to come up with a generic way to script this (within reasonable time).  Am seriously considering a bounty for it.

Comment: ok I'm going to take a look