# Is there a way to extract brush textures (alphas) from a .blend file?

Tags: transparency, sculpting, blend-files

https://www.blendswap.com/blend/20195

I downloaded the rock brushes from the link above to use in blender. I would like to use these same textures in ZBRUSH as alphas, but I cannot figure out how to locate or extract the files.

Ive attached a screenshot of what the folder of the downloaded file looks like, as you can see I am only to see the .blend file. Is there a way to look at the content within that file in order to get the textures?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to extract the textures from the blend file but you don't have Blender? Why don't you download it? It's free and there is a portable version. The brushes use textures that use images if I remember right. The images are probably packed into the blend file. So you need Blender to export them.

Comment: @blunder yes im using blender, but I need to extract the textures from the blend file. I cant figure out how to export the files from blender, do you know how?

Comment: I've tried to open the blend file (2.7x) on 2 computers with Blender 2.83, 3.4, and 3.5a. It crashes all the time immediately. So, **Plan B**: Open a new blend file, use menu *File > Append > Brushes*, and select all  "RB_..." brushes. Then save the blend just to choose a directory. The brushes come with packed images. Now, you can export all these images with the menu *File > External Data > Unpack Resources* & choose *Use files in the current directory...*. That's where the saved blend file is. Blender will create a folder named "textures" & saves the *.PNG files there. Mission complete :-)

Comment: I'm not sure why your question got closed because it's about Blender and exporting data. IMHO it's more a duplicate of this question: [Is there a way to save the textures used inside a .blend file to a PC?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/183112/107598). Maybe a moderator can fix it.

Comment: @Blunder That may have been a bit hasty decision on my part! Sorry, fixed it.

Comment: @blunder thanks for the link, I ended up unpacking the whole file and it put the textures into a separate file which I saved to my desktop!