# Simple Panel script is not appearing on 3d view

Tags: scripting, add-on

I followed a tutorial on youtube showing how to make a simple panel on blender, i copied it one to one but the panel is no nowhere to be seen. The script runs fine without errors and I have no idea of what is wrong.

I'm using blender 2.90 following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyt0O7saU4Q&list=PLFtLHTf5bnym_wk4DcYIMq1DkjqB7kDb-):

```
import bpy


class TestPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Test Panel"
    bl_idname = "PT_TestPanel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'My 1st Addon'
    
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text = "Sample Text")
        
        
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(TestPanel)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TestPanel)


if __name__ == "__main_":
    register()
```

Comment: You should also add the correct *separator* (`_PT_`) to the name of your panel class according to [2.8x API changes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons). Replace `TestPanel` by `MYADDON_PT_TestPanel` and even more important: assign it to `bl_idname` -> `bl_idname = "MYADDON_PT_TestPanel"` otherwise you'll get an error in the console. Recommend to read: [**How to create a custom UI?**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57332/31447).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing one underscore under the registration above the last line in `__main__`

It reads

```
if __name__ == "__main_":
    register()
```

but is supposed to read

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/134416/15543

Comment: Well just learned something new today, thanks for the link, always wondered what that actually meant.